# Understanding Gradient Policy Deriving

Tags: python, machine-learning, math, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning

I'm trying to recreate very simple example of Policy Gradient, from it's origin resource [Andrej Karpathy blog](http://karpathy.github.io/2016/05/31/rl/). In that articale, you will find example with CartPole and Policy Gradient with list of weight and Softmax activation. Here is my recreated and very simple example of CartPole policy gradient, **which works perfect**.

```
import gym
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
import copy

NUM_EPISODES = 4000
LEARNING_RATE = 0.000025
GAMMA = 0.99


# noinspection PyMethodMayBeStatic
class Agent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.poly = PolynomialFeatures(1)
        self.w = np.random.rand(5, 2)

    def policy(self, state):
        z = state.dot(self.w)
        exp = np.exp(z)
        return exp/np.sum(exp)

    def __softmax_grad(self, softmax):
        s = softmax.reshape(-1,1)
        return np.diagflat(s) - np.dot(s, s.T)

    def grad(self, probs, action, state):
        dsoftmax = self.__softmax_grad(probs)[action,:]
        dlog = dsoftmax / probs[0,action]
        grad = state.T.dot(dlog[None,:])
        return grad

    def update_with(self, grads, rewards):

        for i in range(len(grads)):
            # Loop through everything that happend in the episode
            # and update towards the log policy gradient times **FUTURE** reward

            total_grad_effect = 0
            for t, r in enumerate(rewards[i:]):
                total_grad_effect += r * (GAMMA ** r)
            self.w += LEARNING_RATE * grads[i] * total_grad_effect
            print("Grads update: " + str(np.sum(grads[i])))



def main(argv):
    env = gym.make('CartPole-v0')
    np.random.seed(1)

    agent = Agent()
    complete_scores = []

    for e in range(NUM_EPISODES):
        state = env.reset()[None, :]
        state = agent.poly.fit_transform(state)

        rewards = []
        grads = []
        score = 0

        while True:

            probs = agent.policy(state)
            action_space = env.action_space.n
            action = np.random.choice(action_space, p=probs[0])

            next_state, reward, done,_ = env.step(action)
            next_state = next_state[None,:]
            next_state = agent.poly.fit_transform(next_state.reshape(1, 4))
            grad = agent.grad(probs, action, state)

            grads.append(grad)
            rewards.append(reward)

            score += reward
            state = next_state

            if done:
                break

        agent.update_with(grads, rewards)
        complete_scores.append(score)

    env.close()
    plt.plot(np.arange(NUM_EPISODES),
             complete_scores)
    plt.savefig('image1.png')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(None)
```

[image]

.

.

**Question**

I'm trying to do, almost the same example but with Sigmoid activation (just for simplicity). **That is all I need to do. Switch activation in the model from `softmax` to the `sigmoid`.** Which should work for sure (based on explanation below). But my Policy Gradient model don't learn anything and keeps random. Any suggestion?

```
import gym
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

NUM_EPISODES = 4000
LEARNING_RATE = 0.000025
GAMMA = 0.99


# noinspection PyMethodMayBeStatic
class Agent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.poly = PolynomialFeatures(1)
        self.w = np.random.rand(5, 1) - 0.5

    # Our policy that maps state to action parameterized by w
    # noinspection PyShadowingNames
    def policy(self, state):
        z = np.sum(state.dot(self.w))
        return self.sigmoid(z)

    def sigmoid(self, x):
        s = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))
        return s

    def sigmoid_grad(self, sig_x):
        return sig_x * (1 - sig_x)

    def grad(self, probs, action, state):
        dsoftmax = self.sigmoid_grad(probs)
        dlog = dsoftmax / probs
        grad = state.T.dot(dlog)
        grad = grad.reshape(5, 1)
        return grad

    def update_with(self, grads, rewards):
        if len(grads) < 50:
            return
        for i in range(len(grads)):
            # Loop through everything that happened in the episode
            # and update towards the log policy gradient times **FUTURE** reward

            total_grad_effect = 0
            for t, r in enumerate(rewards[i:]):
                total_grad_effect += r * (GAMMA ** r)
            self.w += LEARNING_RATE * grads[i] * total_grad_effect


def main(argv):
    env = gym.make('CartPole-v0')
    np.random.seed(1)

    agent = Agent()
    complete_scores = []

    for e in range(NUM_EPISODES):
        state = env.reset()[None, :]
        state = agent.poly.fit_transform(state)

        rewards = []
        grads = []
        score = 0

        while True:

            probs = agent.policy(state)
            action_space = env.action_space.n
            action = np.random.choice(action_space, p=[1 - probs, probs])

            next_state, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)
            next_state = next_state[None, :]
            next_state = agent.poly.fit_transform(next_state.reshape(1, 4))

            grad = agent.grad(probs, action, state)
            grads.append(grad)
            rewards.append(reward)

            score += reward
            state = next_state

            if done:
                break

        agent.update_with(grads, rewards)
        complete_scores.append(score)

    env.close()
    plt.plot(np.arange(NUM_EPISODES),
             complete_scores)
    plt.savefig('image1.png')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(None)
```

Plotting all the learning keeps random. Nothing helps with tuning hyper parameters. Below the sample image.

[image]

> **References**:

> 1. [**Deep Reinforcement Learning: Pong from Pixels**](http://karpathy.github.io/2016/05/31/rl/)

> 2. [**An introduction to Policy Gradients with Cartpole and Doom**](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/an-introduction-to-policy-gradients-with-cartpole-and-doom-495b5ef2207f/)

> 3. [**Deriving Policy Gradients and Implementing REINFORCE**](https://medium.com/@thechrisyoon/deriving-policy-gradients-and-implementing-reinforce-f887949bd63)

> 4. [**Machine Learning Trick of the Day (5): Log Derivative Trick 12**](http://blog.shakirm.com/2015/11/machine-learning-trick-of-the-day-5-log-derivative-trick/)

---

**UPDATE**

Seems like answer below could doing some work from the graphic. But it's Not log probability, and Not even gradient of the policy. And changes whole purpose of the RL Gradient Policy. Please check references above. Following the image we next statement.

[image]

I need to take a **Gradient of the Log function of my Policy** (which is simply weights and `sigmoid` activation). Please let me know in case of any questions.

Comment: I suggest you to post this question on [Data Science Stack Exchange](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/) since it is mostly a theoretical question (Stack Overflow is mainly for coding questions). You will also reach more people that are knowledgeable in this domain.

Comment: @Gilles-PhilippePaillé I added code, which represent the problem. What I need to do, it's just to fix some of the parts with activation. Please check the updated answer.

Comment: To Derive Policy Gradients, here is reference article with working example of same type of arrangements, Hopefully you'll learn in detail: https://medium.com/@thechrisyoon/deriving-policy-gradients-and-implementing-reinforce-f887949bd63 .

Comment: @MuhammadUsman . Thank for the info. I red that source. Right now it's clear and form example above, I'm trying to change activation from `softmax` to `signmoid`. That is only one thing I need to do in example above.

Comment: Your Agent class defines the grad to be the softmax and not sigmoid.

Comment: @BryceWayne I didn't get you. I have another file with full changes to support sigmoid activation.

Comment: I might be pointing somethign weird here, but wouldn't if(len(grads)) < 50 Not perform any learning unless length of your episode is > 50 timesteps? And from the plot given that most of your episodes are <50 there would essentially be no training? (assuming cartpole +1 score per timestep where it isnt dead)

Comment: @Jason Chia You're right, but I have experimented with it and reducing it generally doesn't have noticable effect in this particular case.

Comment: @PavelTyshevskyi Well if you have tested it, then the problem would reside in either the learning gradient and/or the model. Could also be the method of the probabilities. If I am not mistaken, sum of probabilities of sigmoid function is not necessarily = 1, whereas softmax is. As such, the agent choice with the given probabilities could be wrong since 1-probs is not exactly the action space probabilities? Btw this is for the standard pole cart environment? Ill probably try a solution later.

Comment: @JasonChia sigmoid outputs real number in range `[0, 1]` that can be interpreted as probability of positive action (turn right in CartPole, for example). Then probability of negative action (turn left) is `1 - sigmoid`. Sum of this probabilities is 1.

Yes, this is a standart pole card environment.

Comment: @JasonChia In fact it should work, because example above is very simple.Just raw weight with simple activation. Output - probability of going left. All other cases - going right.

Comment: According to [this](https://spinningup.openai.com/en/latest/spinningup/rl_intro.html) 
 definition, in your code, the following line:  
  
`total_grad_effect += r * (GAMMA ** r)`  
  
shouldn't be:  
  
`total_grad_effect += r * (GAMMA ** t)`?  
  
That is, t instead of r for the exponent?

Comment: @AGPX In your reference above there is no mention for PG, but general introduction to other value functions. Can you be more specific.

Answer (score 13):

The problem is with `grad` method.

```py
def grad(self, probs, action, state):
    dsoftmax = self.sigmoid_grad(probs)
    dlog = dsoftmax / probs
    grad = state.T.dot(dlog)
    grad = grad.reshape(5, 1)
    return grad
```

In the original code Softmax was used along with CrossEntropy loss function. When you switch activation to Sigmoid, the proper loss function becomes Binary CrossEntropy. Now, the purpose of `grad` method is to calculate gradient of the loss function wrt. weights. [Sparing](https://ml-cheatsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/logistic_regression.html#gradient-descent) the details, proper gradient is given by `(probs - action) * state` in the terminology of your program. The last thing is to add minus sign - we want to maximize the negative of the loss function.

Proper `grad` method thus:

```py
def grad(self, probs, action, state):
    grad = state.T.dot(probs - action)
    return -grad
```

Another change that you might want to add is to increase learning rate.
`LEARNING_RATE = 0.0001` and `NUM_EPISODES = 5000` will produce the following plot:

[image: Correct mean reward vs num of episodes]

The convergence will be much faster if weights are initialized using Gaussian distribution with zero mean and small variance:

```
def __init__(self):
    self.poly = PolynomialFeatures(1)
    self.w = np.random.randn(5, 1) * 0.01
```

[image]

**UPDATE**

Added complete code to reproduce the results:

```
import gym
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures

NUM_EPISODES = 5000
LEARNING_RATE = 0.0001
GAMMA = 0.99


# noinspection PyMethodMayBeStatic
class Agent:
    def __init__(self):
        self.poly = PolynomialFeatures(1)
        self.w = np.random.randn(5, 1) * 0.01

    # Our policy that maps state to action parameterized by w
    # noinspection PyShadowingNames
    def policy(self, state):
        z = np.sum(state.dot(self.w))
        return self.sigmoid(z)

    def sigmoid(self, x):
        s = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))
        return s

    def sigmoid_grad(self, sig_x):
        return sig_x * (1 - sig_x)

    def grad(self, probs, action, state):
        grad = state.T.dot(probs - action)
        return -grad

    def update_with(self, grads, rewards):
        if len(grads) < 50:
            return
        for i in range(len(grads)):
            # Loop through everything that happened in the episode
            # and update towards the log policy gradient times **FUTURE** reward

            total_grad_effect = 0
            for t, r in enumerate(rewards[i:]):
                total_grad_effect += r * (GAMMA ** r)
            self.w += LEARNING_RATE * grads[i] * total_grad_effect


def main(argv):
    env = gym.make('CartPole-v0')
    np.random.seed(1)

    agent = Agent()
    complete_scores = []

    for e in range(NUM_EPISODES):
        state = env.reset()[None, :]
        state = agent.poly.fit_transform(state)

        rewards = []
        grads = []
        score = 0

        while True:

            probs = agent.policy(state)
            action_space = env.action_space.n
            action = np.random.choice(action_space, p=[1 - probs, probs])

            next_state, reward, done, _ = env.step(action)
            next_state = next_state[None, :]
            next_state = agent.poly.fit_transform(next_state.reshape(1, 4))

            grad = agent.grad(probs, action, state)
            grads.append(grad)
            rewards.append(reward)

            score += reward
            state = next_state

            if done:
                break

        agent.update_with(grads, rewards)
        complete_scores.append(score)

    env.close()
    plt.plot(np.arange(NUM_EPISODES),
             complete_scores)
    plt.savefig('image1.png')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(None)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try this solution later.

Comment: I'm not sure, where you take such derivation for my function. As you can check image above. I would need to take **gradient of the log of the policy**. Where Policy in my case simply weights with `sigmoid`. But your gradient in answer should nothing to do with my gradient. Right?

Comment: Notice that you don't incorporate any information about what action was performed. According to [this lecture on Policy Gradients (slide 13)](https://www.cs.toronto.edu/~rgrosse/courses/csc321_2018/slides/lec21.pdf), update should look like `(action - probs) * sigmoid_grad(probs)`, but I omitted `sigmoid_grad` because of the vanishing problem with sigmoid gradient.

Comment: The crux here is to indicate the direction in which we want to change weights. If `action = 1`, we want `probs` to be closer to `1`, increasing the weights (positive gradient). If `action=0`, we want `probs` to be closer to `0`, hence decreasing the weights (negative gradient).

Comment: In any case, changes above doesn't work at all, can you share whole file? AT the same time, I want to make clear sample, and don't care about vanishing problem in this case. And `(action - probs)` it's just another way of changing same wights.

Comment: Ok. But it's not log probability. And not even gradient of the policy? Vanishing gradient, should nothing to do here? because it's propagation only one layer of 4 weights.